# How to add label to the right side of checkbox in odoo-12

Tags: html, checkbox, label, odoo-12, formview

Hi im trying to design my checkbox in odoo i want it to have a label to the right side of the checkbox just like this
[image]

Any Idea how can I Achieve this?

I've tried adding `<span>Percentage</span>` After my field but its always breaking the line

Comment: Can you try to use "< div >" ?
Regards,
Mustufa Rangwala (Probuse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two checkbox fields `chk1` and `chk2`, To make them appear like in the picture you will need to:

Add two labels one with `Discount Mode` string and another with an empty string.
Add a `div` after each label which will contain the field and its label.

```
<group>
    <label for="chk1" string="Discount Mode"/>
    <div class="o_row">
        <field name="chk1"/>
        <label for="chk1"/>
    </div>

    <label for='chk2' string=""/>
    <div class="o_row">
        <field name="chk2"/>
        <label for="chk2"/>
    </div>
</group>
```

You can refer to [weight field](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/386abc1fe83233a4b69fe17833b7ea654b5df011/addons/product/views/product_views.xml#L98) in `Product -> Inventory (tab) -> logistics (group)`.